# Scala => with =

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to understand Spark internals and also new to Scala. I would like to ask the meaning of `(index, res) => results(index) = res` in this statement in SparkContext.scala:

```
runJob[T, U](rdd, func, partitions, (index, res) => results(index) = res)
```

source: [SparkContext.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2032)

The two things that confound me is the usage of the `=>` and `=` in the same expression, and the grouping/precedence (should it be interpreted with the `=>` first, or `=` first then `=>`?).

The usage of `=>` doesn't seem to match any of the usages of `=>` i read online, and it's not clear what `= res` is doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(index, res) => ...` means an anonymous function that receives two parameters (`index` and `res`).

`results(index) = res` is the body of the function.

What the function does is to assign `res` to `results` on the `index` position.